# Products do not show up in front end

Tags: magento-1.8

As shown in the picture i have a category speakers having one item(product - Mini Car Speaker) and one category that is empty.
[image]
But when i try to access this from the front-end it does not show up. See:
[image]
and
[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to ensure the following:

-the product is assigned to a category

-the product is assigned to a store view.

-the product is In Stock

-the product has a qty assigned

Once this has been done, flush the store cache and the product will appear.

Comment: Nopes, but still thanks for trying

Comment: In some lesser cases, the attributes may be set on a store level. I've had several instances of products set to disabled for specific stores, where the default values were overridden.

Comment: You might need to reindex data also.

Comment: Anyone know me what's issue when i set manage inventory no for magento website?

Answer (score 6):

The checklist for whether items are in stock follows. Some will seem stupid until the first time you spend an hour trying to figure this problem out:

1. The products must be Visible in Catalog.
2. The products must be Enabled.
3. Product must have a stock Quantity.
4. The product must be set to In Stock.
5. If the product is set not to track stock, it still has to have a stock Quantity and be set to In Stock.
6. The product must be assigned to the target Category.
7. If using multi-website mode (or if you imported the products through Data Flow), the products must be assigned to the target Website.
8. You must refresh your Cache / Indices, just to make sure.

Welcome to Magento. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the quantity of the product is not 0 and also that the product is listed available in stock. Because by default the products not in stock are not listed and also by default the quantity of the product is 0 when added.

So what you have to do is go to Catalog->Manage Products Click on your product and edit it, Go to inventory in the left bar and then change the quantity to more than 0 and also change the stock availability to in stock.

Comment: @sr_magento I am sorry, but when i posted the question i was unaware about the answer; it just got struck in my mind and i came up with a solution. I am sorry :P

Answer (score 0):

The product has position 0. This can cause the product to disappear. I had the same issue and resolved it by changing the position to a number higher than 0. You can still order your products with the numbers but simply don't use 0.

Comment: Can you back up this claim with some code or an example?

Comment: I don't think this is it. I'we worked on a lot of projects that did not have positions set to products

Comment: Ok, so this might be a bug in my install? I thought it could be helpful but correct me if I'm wrong. I'm quite new to Magento and noticed this "quirck" in my install.

Answer (score 0):

if you have it in custom block or even category block that inserted manually  , then be sure that you have created permission  for that block from system >> permissions >> blocks, that have been a real problem on recent versions of magento 1.9.x