# Uploaded images not appearing on frontend and backend with a Broken image symbol

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend, product-images, backend

I have uploaded images to products. It has been viewed then in backend and frontend it is not appearing.

I have checked with stackoverflow answers like
[Products do not show up in front end](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16085/products-do-not-show-up-in-front-end)

and checked. everything is perfect.

But Now it is showing Broken Image symbol in backend and Magento no image at front end.

If I upload new image to the product page, it is showing the new picture to that product, but old uploaded images remain as a broken image.

Please help to fix it. I have more than 1000 products on site.

Comment: Hi, tell me please, If you check image src, what url do you see there?

Answer (score 3):

- Check the file access rights for the image folder. Files there should have 664, Folder should be on 775
- Check if the image gets written in image cache `media/products/cache/...`

What have you don recently? Any changes on the site?

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping out. I have changed the access rights and cleared cache. but still it is not working. I have installed several extensions and removed all those and installed a new theme.

Comment: Switch you theme to default view. Still not? The deactive all installed extension and active them one by one (do not forget the cache thing while doing that). Did you try to access a picture from the browser path? Does it show?

Answer (score 2):

As you have told that when you upload new images, those images show up with products, but old images remain like broken images, it means that either the images are not at right place or it can be a simple re-indexing problem.

Please check first by re-indexing. If it does not solve your problem, please share what you have done till now.