# new products not appearing on the front end

Tags: product, category

New products don't appear on the front end after creating them. I ensured to tick all the boxes of checklists like [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/29447/17221). Older products are there fine. I'm creating them manually rather than importing, making sure everything is in stock, activated, in the correct category etc.

Apart from making sure the different store views are ok, quantities etc in my first link above, I've also tried indexing all, flushing all caches, truncating the core_url_rewrite table (now small). I thought it could be cron related but `n98-magerun.phar sys:cron:history` shows the jobs returning a success message. (I made sure the cron process was owned by the correct user).

What else could it be? I check the logs but nothing stands out of the ordinary. Could it be permission-related? These are my current settings.

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;  
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
chmod 550 mage
```

Comment: they don't appear on the category page or the individual link returns a 404? if the second one then go to url rewrites and check where the product is pointing to.

Comment: it's just the category pages. i can follow the url rewrite links to the product pages ok (with the category in the url), but the category pages themselves show only older products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was that there was an extension that was filtering on fields that were no longer being updated on the newly-created items, so only items that adhered to the previous format were shown.