# Not showing newly added products in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog, importexport, import-products

I have import products through magmi, products is imported successfully, but the products are not showing in frontend, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Do reindex from backend : **System > Index  Management** and it will work....

below links will guide you :

https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-issue-a-reindex-in-magento.html

https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-re-index-data-and-in-what-cases-it-is-needed.html

https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/magento-reindex-command-line-and-what-to-do-if-reindex-is-not-working

Comment: Yes, i am re indexing and also clear  the cache but its not showing

Comment: @SauravKumarSeth are products there in backend ? also check the product through `sitename.com/product-url` in browser....

Comment: previously its showing perfectly, after deleted all products from sql query, then creating new one its not working

Comment: Yes, products is showing in backend, and all products is instock with 100 qty

Comment: @SauravKumarSeth this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16085/products-do-not-show-up-in-front-end/16086) may help.....

Comment: My products is in 'White board ' category

Comment: @SauravKumarSeth what you see when you tried with 
`42.104.73.12/product-url`